# log4net fails to find thread id when running under unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, log4net, mstest

I have log4net which writes entries like:

```
<conversionPattern value="[%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%property{machineName}] [%property{pid}] [%thread] [%-5level]: %message%newline"/>
```

It all works fine except when running unit tests. If I do not mock the logger and the tests use the real object then instead of a threadId I get

```
Agent: adapter run thread for test 'Log4NetLogger_TestLoggingMachineNamePrinted' with id '84e27809-f2b8-45b4-a2e1-ce305d20bc0c'
```

So obviously log4net gets confused when it is being used from a test runner. If I run the app normally then I get a normal thread id.

Anyone knows a workaround for that? I am using MSTest. Same behaviour happens with the MSTest test runner and the R# test runner.

Thank you in advance for reading my question.

George

Comment: Why do you need log in unit test???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a reference to log4net in the unit tests project may do the trick (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598964/687857)).

Having said that, you probably don't need logging in this case (unless these are really Integration tests), so it is best to use a [Stub](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) instead of your real logger object.